# How to change breadcrumbs highlight background color in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, breadcrumbs, appearance

How to change breadcrumbs background color on crumb hover?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it uses the same color as **"Caret Row" style** .. and just automatically makes it lighter (darker the color the bigger difference will be):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As the breadcrumb changed appearance in 2017.2, this can now also be configured better. Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Breadcrumbs (Windows/Linux) or PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor > General > Breadcrumbs for macOS. There you can press "Manage colors" to get to the options pictured above.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-with-breadcrumbs.html

Answer (score -1):

This effect currently not disable.

Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139930