# How to stop PhpStorm 9 from highlighting file when hovering over breadcrumb

Tags: phpstorm

I've just updated PhpStorm to version 9 and get this highlight of the entire file / class when hovering over this field (where it says `\optimizer\Console\Commands\GetSellerinfo`):

[image]

The file gets this grey highlight when hovering over above field.

[image]

I've searched the settings but didn't find the right one. Does somebody know how to disable this? I've imported my settings from version 8 and didn't had this highlighting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATM there is no such option.

It uses your caret row color (just [automatically makes it lighter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113655/783119) so it's more visible) and not some separate style which you can disable/modify.

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139930 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress (when devs will introduce such option or disable such behaviour).

Comment: The ticket you sent me was closed and fixed yesterday. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > uncheck Show HTML breadcrumbs.

Close and reopen PhpStorm and the breadcrumb will disappear.

Comment: Thank you. I need the breadcrumb, I only want to remove the highlight on hover

Comment: Ah, I see...I don't see a setting for that.