# Change background color of highlighted HTML elements

Tags: ide, phpstorm

When I hover the mouse on a HTML tag in the tiny bar under the file tab, the background of the highlighted element is very bright, and the text becomes unreadable.
 I couldn't find a way to customize this in the settings, can somebody help?

Here's what I mean:

[image]

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30113655/783119 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/31314139/783119 P.S. It's fixed, but not in current 141.xx branch

Comment: Thanks, I've disabled the "Show HTML breadcrumbs" option, until the fix goes live to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses your caret row color (it just [automatically makes it lighter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113655/783119) so it's more visible) and not some separate style which you can disable/modify.

---

ATM there is no option to disable such behaviour. I mean -- [IDEA-139930](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139930) ticket is fixed, but not available in 141.xx branch that PhpStorm is currently built on.

If it annoys you a lot then right now I may only suggest to disable that breadcrumbs bar altogether until PhpStorm will move to 142.xx or newer branch. For that: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Appearance | Show HTML breadcrumbs` (you will have to close and reopen that file to see the changes).

Answer (score 0):

You should post more info about specification: exact version of PhpStorm etc.

Try this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html